# Clicking on the element (say one or many image tag(s)) and a same function should be called in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Considering my knowledge in jQuery where

```
$("img").click(function(){
    // functionality
});
```

So in the above scenario, on click of any img tag, the functionality works.I need not write `onclick` for each and every img tag in this case.What is the equivalent in AngularJS?

(`ng-click` of AngularJS is similar to `onclick` of Javascript)

Comment: The ngClick directive allows you to specify custom behavior when an element is clicked.

Comment: There is no similar functionality built in to Angular.  You can write directives to do that.  Or, often when there are a lot of elements that have the same functionality they are rendered as part of an `ng-repeat`, so the `ng-click` would only need to be added once within the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `img` directive

```
app.directive('img', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    priority: 10000,
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var clickedMe = function() {
        alert("clicked");
      }
      element.bind('click', clickedMe);
    }
  }
});
```